# UsbManager NoDefClass error on Galaxy S5570 with Android 2.3.5

Tags: android, usb, hardware, future

I am having problem with deploying application to Galaxy-Mini S5570 with Android 2.3.5

I have ensured that everything is set right:

- `AndroidManifest.xml` has 
  `<uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="10"
      android:targetSdkVersion="10" />`
- target is set to Google APIS 10
- i have added to use libraries 
  `<uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" android:required="false"/>` (if i set `false` to `true`) then deploying ends with 
  `[2013-05-24 03:02:49 - MainActivity] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
  [2013-05-24 03:02:49 - MainActivity] Please check logcat output for more details.
  [2013-05-24 03:02:49 - MainActivity] Launch canceled!`

after deploying and trying to run the app I am getting error

`05-24 02:33:54.949: E/AndroidRuntime(2311): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.future.usb.UsbManager`

I have even added `usb.jar` from `adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130514\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-10\libs` to project libraries, but even though, this did not fix the problem.

Looks like the library is really not deployed to phone, 
what to do? Android doc is saying that Android 2.3.5 (API 10) supports Android Accessories.